# passing a column name as a variable to an ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have a query:

```rb
Foo.where("lower(bar) LIKE ?", "%#{baz}%")
```

which transforms to plain SQL as:

```sql
    ... WHERE (lower(bar) LIKE ...
```

and works perfectly. But instead of `bar` I want to pass an argument. So I tried to rewrite it like this:

```rb
Foo.where("lower(?) LIKE ?", bar, "%#{baz}%")
```

where `bar` is a variable containing a string `'bar'`. In this case it stops working and transforms to plain SQL as:

```
... WHERE (lower('bar') LIKE ...
```

So how can I make this query work?

Comment: That looks like the appropriate behavior for wildcards to me. You want to have the variable name inserted into `lower()` instead of the value held within the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try using sprintf-style % escapes in the template to avoid the the column name you wish to interpolate from being quoted:

```
Foo.where("lower(%s) LIKE '%s'", bar, "%#{baz}%")
```

(N.B. The single quotes around the second `%s` - the second argument does want to be quoted)

[Reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where):

> Lastly, you can use sprintf-style % escapes in the template. This works slightly differently than the previous methods; you are responsible for ensuring that the values in the template are properly quoted. The values are passed to the connector for quoting, but the caller is responsible for ensuring they are enclosed in quotes in the resulting SQL. After quoting, the values are inserted using the same escapes as the Ruby core method Kernel::sprintf.

Comment: it looks vulnerable to sql injections

Comment: Source indicates `%s` sprintf style conditions are sanitized by Rails, like the other styles: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b75d6ea5d35d61c60f2675ed956c51e71d2b07ad/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L17-L18

Comment: i see. then it is also a suitable solution

Answer (score 2):

You can construct your query via Arel:

```rb
bar = :field_name # or 'string_name'.to_sym
Foo.where(Foo.arel_table[bar].lower.matches("%#{baz}%"))
```

Comment: `arel` is always the best option; however `"%#{baz.to_s.downcase}%"` is probably more fitting  :)